# The audio on the back panel seems not to be working. [Ubuntu 18.10]

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hardware, audio-jack

there's a pesky problem i'm having with one, if not all Linux distributions based on Ubuntu (And including itself) or Fedora.
The back panel of my computer seems to be not working for audio at all. And being the noob I am at Linux, i don't exactly know what's going on, and plus, this happens on EVERY Linux Distro, even Android. The front panel kind of works, but only when the cable is veeeery loose, barely connected (which is a known problem of such panel, this is the reason i want to use the rear.).
Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I fixed the problem with Qasmixer. Seems like it wanted to keep muting the device with no reason at all. It fixed itself when i disabled both front line out and auto mute. :P